# VS Code Code Runner C++ with wrong command in terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I'm using Code Runner extension in VS Code to run C++ code and it's using the wrong terminal command to do so. I'm using git-bash in VS Code and Windows 10.

This is the command in terminal:

```
Douglas@LAPTOP-6BSNLLDB MINGW64 /c/path (master)
$ cd "c:\path\" && g++ HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld && "c:\path\"HelloWorld
bash: cd: c:\path" && g++ HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld && c:path"HelloWorld: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, it's using `cd` and `g++` correctly, but the command to actually run the `.exe` file is wrong.
Shouldn't it be `"c:\path\HellowWorld.exe"`?

How can I change this? It works correctly with python.

If I can't, how do I run C++ code within VS Code?

Comment: Bash doesn't know anything about Windows path names or .exe files.  Ought to be /c/path/HelloWorld

Comment: Do you have to use git-bash terminal for compiling the C++ program? Looks like the commands are coming from extension itself and they are compatible with Windows terminal, not with bash.

Comment: I was using bash because a friend told me to since I could use it on Linux and Windows. Changing it to powershell worked fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using git-bash instead of PowerShell.

you only need to use

```json
"code-runner.terminalRoot": "/",
```

[VSCode: Code Runner extension is unable to execute the code on git bash terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62721028/vscode-code-runner-extension-is-unable-to-execute-the-code-on-git-bash-terminal)

---

Change setting to

```json
"code-runner.executorMap":{
 "cpp": "cd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && ./$fileNameWithoutExt",
}
```

also c's: ( I use tcc)

```json
"code-runner.executorMap":{
 "c": "cd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash && tcc -run $fileNameWithoutExt.c",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cd /d "c:\path\" && g++ HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld && HelloWorld
```

- Or..

```
$ cd /d "c:\path\" && g++ HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld.exe && HelloWorld
```

Comment: That is the problem, how do I change the quotes?

Comment: Your are in path: cd "c:\path\" run only `HelloWorld`

Comment: && means that: [commandA && commandB      Run commandA, if it succeeds then run commandB](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0):

What wuyudi said before isn't false, but I think instead of

```
"code-runner.termnalRoot":"/",
```

you should use

```
"code-runner.terminalRoot":"/mnt/"
```

it's working fine for me so I hope it will work for the others too.