# Code Runner not executing in windows in git bash

Tags: json, bash, git, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

[image: Git Bash Output]

```
"code-runner.terminalRoot":"/",
"code-runner.executorMap": {
"cpp": "cd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash && g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && ./$fileNameWithoutExt"
}
```

These are my settings.json which when i try to run on windows 10(vscode gitbash) gives the error above, i've changed it to many ways, but it seems not working, can you help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode: Code Runner extension is unable to execute the code on git bash terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62721028/vscode-code-runner-extension-is-unable-to-execute-the-code-on-git-bash-terminal)

Comment: No, i've already checked the post.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are using is not `bash`.

Try something like

```
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
   ...
fi
```

Comment: I am not using any syntax, just pressing f9 code runner is converting && into if($?){}

Comment: give me escape sequence which i can put before &&